# I want to fetch data from a website and put in MySQL workbench, but it's not working

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, mysql-workbench

First time programmer here, please don't be harsh on me.

I want to fetch data from the URL's and put it inside MYSQL workbench database, it says that it's working, see image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XhVK.png). But it's not doing so, what is wrong in the script?

```
# GET ALL WorldRecords from https://api.isuresults.eu/records
import requests
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
from helper_db import make_db_connection
engine = make_db_connection

def get_isu_worldrecord_db(engine):
    URL = "https://api.isuresults.eu/records/?type=WR"
    df_final=pd.DataFrame()

    for i in range(1,20):
        params = {'page': i}
        api = requests.get(url=URL, params=params)
        data = api.json()
        df = json_normalize(data,'results')
        df_final=df_final.append(df,ignore_index=True,sort=False)

    df_final=df_final.drop(['laps'], axis=1)

    df_final.to_sql("Tester", con=engine,if_exists="replace", chunksize=1000)
    return
```

Answer (score 1):

You define this method, but you don't really run it.

Add another line at the last:

```
get_isu_worldrecord_db(engine)
```